# How to define custom colors in MathJax in config?

Tags: colors, mathjax

**Note:** I know that I can define custom colors in MathJax by `$$\definecolor{somecolor}{RGB}{1243,45,46}$$` and then use it as `$$\color{somecolor}{test}$$`.

**Question:** However, I would like to define the color in a MathJax config object i.e. I don't want to render same command e.g. `$$\definecolor{somecolor}{RGB}{1243,45,46}$$` on every page whenever I need the color. Therefore I'm looking for a solution that would look like this.

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: {
    // I can use this extension
    extensions: ["color.js"]
  }
  // I would like to define my custom colors here.
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("TeX color Ready", function() {
     var color = MathJax.Extension["TeX/color"];
     color.colors["somecolor"] = color.getColor('RGB','123,45,46');
});
```

to the bottom of your configuration block (or if you're using [plain JS](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html#using-plain-javascript), put it in the `AuthorInit` call).

**Update**

To answer the question from the comments, you can use HTML colors in the configuration by writin directly to the color object.

```
MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("TeX color Ready", function() {
     MathJax.Extension["TeX/color"].colors["somecolor"] = '#2B2B2B';
});
```

Comment: It feels like there should be a simpler way but I don't see it.  I'll ask our lead developer next week.

Comment: Can I do `color.getColor('HTML','009688')`?

Comment: Yes. I almost put that in there but your examples was rgb.

Comment: You can also just write to the color.colors object.

Comment: I do `Object.assign();` to merge custom colors with predefined ones.
I get `Error: Color model 'HTML' not defined` any idea why?

Comment: [Link to live code snippet.](https://codepen.io/MaciejCaputa/pen/zzdavz)
**Config:** `MathJax.Hub.Config({ TeX: { extensions: ["color.js"] }});` and `TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML`.

Comment: I checked [the source code of color.js](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/blob/master/extensions/TeX/color.js) it looks that there is no implementation for `HTML` color. It only is implemented for `rgb` and `RGB`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example config using HTML color.

Comment: Thank you, note that I had to add # to make it work.

Comment: Does this still work with MathJax3?

Comment: @pglpm no, the APIs for v3 are completely different.

Answer (score 1):

If the most important thing is to have a central location where colors are defined once, an alternate solution is to use the TeX extension "HTML.js" ([found here](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html)) in the MathJax config file to define custom colors using CSS. To the MathJax config file, under TeX, add the extension:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: {
    extensions: ["HTML.js"] //plus any other extensions
  }
});
```

Then you can define all custom colors in the CSS as classes and apply them to expressions with `\{class}{math}`. For example, the CSS could have classes for each color (here "red" and "blue").

**CSS**

```
.red {color: #FF0011;}
.blue {color: #2200FF;}
```

Then `$$\class{red}{a+b} + \class{blue}{c}$$` will create the expression "a + b + c" where "a + b" is that shade of red, and "c" is that shade of blue.